# sorl-thumbnail and file renaming

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

having a similar model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    img = ImageWithThumbnailsField(upload_to='uploads/',thumbnail={'size': (56, 34)})
```

It works fine but I want to add 2 more features to it:

1- It should also generate a second thumbnail sized 195x123, in addition to 56x34

2- While saving the model original image and it's two thumbnails should be renamed as by using the slug.

For instance

I am uploading 1.jpg and I name slug as "i-like-this-country2"
I should save these named versions should be saved:

```
1- i-like-this-country2_original.jpg
2- i-like-this-country2_middle.jpg  #for 195x123
3- i-like-this-country2_small.jpg #for 56x34
```

Answer (score 3):

**First part:**

Just pass it in like this:  `sizes=( (56,34), (195,123), )`

**Second part:**

You can specify a function for the `upload_to` which Django will call, passing it an instance of the model and the original filename.  With that, you can put together a function that renames the file based on the slug because Django will use whatever you return it instead.  Untested code, but something like this:

```
def _Foo_img_name(instance, filename):
    # grab the extension
    left_path, extension = self.file.name.rsplit('.',1)

    # change the filename then return
    return 'uploads/%s.%s' % (instance.slug, extension)

class Foo(models.Model):
    img = ImageWithThumbnailsField(upload_to=_Foo_img_name, ... )
```

I don't believe you can do is change the `<filename>_56x34.jpg` into anything but that.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to create a method in your models.py like this:

```
def rename_file(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    rename = "rename_here"
    return rename + "." + extension
```

Then in the class that extends `models.Model`

```
class MyImage(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(upload_to=rename_file)
```

Don't forget to import from `sorl.thumbnail import ImageField` too!